# Passwordless connect a remote server from vagrant vm through ssh (rsync)

Tags: ssh, vagrant, rsync

I'd like to run a rsync command from a vagrant vm to a remote server (to push files) without the need for a password.

So, the involved machines are: host, guest vm and remote

host is authorized on remote via authorized_keys, however when I run the rsync command from the vm I get asked for a password.

Is there a way to get passwordless rsync from the vm using the keys on the already-authorized host?

I'd like to avoid copying a new authorized key to the remote every time I create a vm.
Also, adding my server's password in the vagrant file is not an option.

Comment: Rsync uses ssh as transport, therefore the pubkey authentication should work. Maybe you're executing the rsync command as different user?

Answer (score 0):

Use ssh key forwarding via [`ssh-agent`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent). Follow these steps:

On your host machine:

```
ssh-add PATH_TO_KEY <use Tab if unsure>
vagrant ssh
```

In the vagrant box edit your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host name_or_ip_of_remote
    ForwardAgent yes
```

Now try to connect to the remote from the vagrant box:

```
ssh name_or_ip_of_remote
```

It should work without a password. As `rsync` is using ssh under the hood, it will work without a password too.

Comment: The host can be a Windows machine and I don't have `ssh-add` there.

Also PATH_TO_KEY points to the private key of the authorized machine, yes?

Comment: fwiw, I have set `config.ssh.forward_agent = true` in my vagrantfile but it seems it's not enough by itself

Comment: No, it doesn't. As previously mentioned, ssh-add is not available on Windows

Comment: Check this: http://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-do-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key I hope it helps